# Escape forward slashes in hook_update_n() descriptions for display on update.php

Tags: 7, updating

I've created a module update function:

```
/**
 * Create alias for node/add/video-submission.
 */
function my_module_update_7103()
{
  // magic
}
```

But on update.php the message shows up without the forward slashes:

> 7103 - Create alias for nodeaddvideo-submission.

What can I do to force the forward slashes to display?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that line 1161 of includes/update.inc is this:

```
$description = str_replace(array("\n", '*', '/'), '', $func->getDocComment());
```

(replaces new lines, asterisks and forward slashes in the doxygen comment with blank strings, everything else is considered to be the update description)

I'd say you have two options:

1. Use an HTML entity:

   ```
   /**
    * Create alias for node&#47;add&#47;video-submission.
    */
   ```
2. Patch the offending line with something like:

   ```
   $description = str_replace(array("\n", '/*', '*/', '*'), '', $func->getDocComment());
   ```

Comment: I'd go with the first option, since patching the core is a very bad practice.

Comment: Yeah, don't use the second option. Can't remember if I actually used the second option or just mistyped my comment and meant I used the first option. @ЕлинЙ is correct, no patching core.